# Large file uploading (GB of data) using Liferay

Tags: java, file-upload, configuration, liferay, large-files

Is it possible to send/upload a large file (cca 2GB) using Liferay and 
`UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);`?

I understand that data transmission is limited by default to 104857600 B but I found out that by changing the limit to 0 the amount of sent data should be unlimited. Temporary storage directory should be used to avoid OutOfMemoryException or something like that (I guess..)

Screenshot of Control panel of Liferay with File Uploads Settings:[Control Panel, Administration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM4Kv.png)

Is it possible to send 2GB file using this technique? If so, please, could you tell me how, and what settings shall I use for the Limit and Temporary Storage Directory?

If this solution is not working what is the best way to do it using Liferay?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve? What is your use case?

Comment: I am trying to upload 2GB files to server. I am using traditional approach of file sending in Java `FileChannel` and `FileInputStream, FileOutputStream` which works fine for smaller files and successfully stores them in the directory on server. But the same approach doesn't work for large files and I am getting `SecurityPortletContainerWrapper` warning.

Comment: I'd like to refer you to this: https://web.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6428002
they were able to upload up to 4GB to a document library, I'm sure that will help you. 
Cheers

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Please accept my answer as correct then :-) so that people having the same question will find an answer quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness:

To increase the file size of your uploads add the following lines to your portal-ext.properties file (that is found in your bundle dir, in LR 7 if installed as bundle):

```
com.liferay.portal.upload.UploadServletRequestImpl.max.size=524288000
dl.file.max.size=0
```

Source:
https://web.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6428002